# GoogleAppsScript - customfunction completion works randomly

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, jsdoc, custom-function

For a few days I've tried to understand why the auto-completion (in the sheet) is working for my customfunction in one Google Sheet and not in another one.
I even copied/pasted the code in the 2nd .gs but no in the second Spreadsheet I can only see original built-in functions.
I did put the @customfunction in my JSdoc of course.

You can see my 2 screenshots.
I've tried a lot of things around casing and spaces and checked every differences between the 2 sheets.
There is none. I'm out of ideas. Please help me figure it out!

Please note that the function workfs perfectly if I enter the formula manually 'till the end.

[image: Code]

[image: Sheet]

Comment: I see no screen shots

Comment: Indeed, sorry I forgot. Here they are!

Comment: It might be something else in the global scope: other functions, other function's comments, and global variables, if any

Comment: I can't see anything. Have you something in mind?

Comment: Hello @Candide, do you encounter this issue at all times with this particular sheet?

Comment: Yes there is no a race condition.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your error but unfortunately didn't get any errors. This is what I've did: create new spreadsheet, copy paste your `metersToMiles()`, can see intellisense, created a copy of sheet and still can see the intellisense. Probably you should **share your spreadsheet** (no sensitive info)